# Summing up every other array of an array of array of integers using inject

Tags: ruby, arrays, fold

From my understanding of how folding works, given an array of integers and some existing value (say, 2)

```
val = 2
arr = [1,2,3]
```

I can say

```
arr.inject(val) do |r, val|
  r += val
end
```

To add all of the elements to the specified value in some specific order (left to right?).

So now if I had instead an array of arrays of integers like this

```
val = 2
arr = [ [1], [2], [3] ]
```

My logic would be similar, except I now I have an extra layer of arrays:

```
val = arr.inject(val) do |r, arrElmt|
  r = arrElmt.inject(r, :+)
end
```

But now I only want every other element starting with the first element, so I want to ignore the `[2]` and just add up the 1 and 3.

I'm not sure how to do this with a fold so I end up going back to using something like `each_with_index` and then skipping odd indices.

```
val = 2
arr = [ [1], [2], [3] ]

arr.each_with_index do |arrElmt, i|
  next if i.odd?
  val = arrElmt.inject(val, :+)
end
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 3):

If the inner arrays are just one element, you can flatten first. There are probably a dozen ways to do this whole thing in Ruby, many of them a little obtuse-looking, but here's another:

```
val += arr.flatten.values_at(* arr.each_index.select(&:even?)).reduce(:+)
```

This adds up the odd values and adds the result to `val`. It might look incorrect at first, with the `even?` method, but it's because Ruby arrays are `0` index based.

Comment: You could also write that: `arr.flatten.values_at(*(0...arr.size).step(2)).reduce(:+)`. lunker, you need to lighten up (your picture, that is).

Comment: @CarySwoveland hehe, thanks for the tip(s) (+1). It's hard to lurk in the light, though. :)

Comment: View it as a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
val = arr.each_slice(2).inject(val) do |total, (even, _odd)|
   even.inject(total, :+)
end
```

`each_slice(n)` yields items n at a time. In this case it will first yield first & second items, then third and fourth and so on. Then I use only the first element of each of these pairs in the sum. If you wanted to sum the odd indices then you'd just change `pair[0]` to `pair[1] || []`

That said, you could probably argue that your original attempt was clearer.

Comment: Your assignment to `r` doesn't do anything. `r` is a local variable of the block, it will go out of scope anyway. You could clear this up a bit using destructuring bind of the block parameters: `|r, (first, _)|`. And there's no need to iterate over an array with one element, just extract the element.

Comment: Oops too much copy/paste. while in the example the inner arrays are all 1 item long , I didn't want to assume that.

Comment: Just a small thing, but I think it reads better if you destructure as  @Jörg suggests, except I wouldn't use a placeholder for the second argument. Instead I'd write `|r, (even, odd)| even.inject(r,:+)`. I normally use placeholders (including `*_` at times), but sometimes it's better to use a variable name, to convey information.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I just realized that your version *won't* generate a warning; I just assumed I would. (Apparently, the warning only checks for unused local variables proper, not unused block or method parameter bindings.) The original description of the feature is here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6693

Comment: @Jörg, that's interesting. I noticed the warning only appears when the placeholder variable has been used, does not begin with `_` and Ruby is run with the `-w` flag. Also, by default that flag is not set when using IRB. I do prefer `_odd` to `odd` (and `_`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I figured it out: you need to wrap it in a method and use destructuring. `ruby -we 'def foo; p {|(a, b)| a } end'` will generate the warning, `ruby -we 'p {|(a, b)| a }'` won't, and neither will `ruby -we 'def foo; p {|a, b| a } end'`. (And yeah, you'll need to enable warnings in order to see them; I only turn them off on remote production servers, in development, testing, and in production on my own laptop, I always have them on.)

Comment: That's interesting, and very clear, @Jörg, but I don't understand why no  destructuring => no warning.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Me neither. I assume that when using destructuring, you introduce local variables as opposed to parameters, and the warning only applies to local variables. It's a strange asymmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some fun with destructuring bind of parameters:

```
arr.each_slice(2).inject(val) {|acc, ((el, *_), _)| acc + el }
```

A more serious way would be:

```
arr.each_slice(2).inject(val) {|acc, (el, _)| acc.+(*el) }
```

or

```
arr.each_slice(2).inject(val) {|acc, (el, _)| acc + el.first }
```

Something closer to your original attempt:

```
arr.each_with_index.inject(val) {|acc, (el, i)|
  if i.odd? then acc else acc + el.first end }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
def sum_even_elements(arr)
  arr.each_slice(2).map(&:first).flatten.reduce(:+)
end

sum_even_elements([1,2,3,4,5])                     #=> 9 
sum_even_elements([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])           #=> 9 
sum_even_elements([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,0]]) #=> 23
```

If needed:

```
def sum_odd_elements(arr)
  arr.flatten.reduce(:+) - sum_even_elements(arr)
end
```

Inefficient? Yes, but just a small cost to make it read well.